# Cannot resolve domain while sending a ping

Tags: php, freebsd, lighttpd, ping

I can't ping any domain from my dedicated server:

```
# ping google.com
ping: cannot resolve google.com: Host name lookup failure
# ping stackoverflow.com
ping: cannot resolve stackoverflow.com: Host name lookup failure
```

It was working fine earlier - I have no idea what was changed.

I can access my dedicated server from the www, but I can not reason any domain from the dedicated.

Also, when I want to use an API I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: fopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: hostname nor servname provided, or not known in[..]
```

Whats the problem?

**Edit:**

When I use IP address (like `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4` or normal domain IP address) its working... Its just dont working when I'm using domains.

Comment: check your /etc/resolv.conf, add "nameserver 8.8.8.8" and remove the other nameservers and it should start resolving. PS 8.8.8.8 is google's public DNS server.

Comment: I know its google's public DNS server, but first of all, I dont have `/etc/resolv.conf` file. Even if I add the line you said - there will be problems with other domains... so for every domain I'd like to access I will have to add new line there?

Comment: It will work for all domains/hosts, because it's a recursive DNS.

Comment: @strkol I why can't I add there my dedicated server IP address? ... added what you said, and ping is still not working for the `google.pl` and others...

Comment: You need to install a recursive dns server (bind, dnscache, or something like that). The best practice is to add your ISP's nameserver there, but I suppose that you don't know it. So 8.8.8.8 should work fine for you. Please paste the result of: "host google.pl 8.8.8.8" command. Also paste the content of /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: @strkol Something went wrong, but now everything is working great. My ISP nameserver is `213.186.33.99`.

Comment: @strkol Would be good if you could answer this question, so I can mark your answer as valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your /etc/resolv.conf, it should contain valid recursive name servers. It should look like (assuming that your ISP's NS is 213.186.33.99):

```
nameserver 213.186.33.99
```

You can check if it's working with host or dig command:

```
host www.google.com 213.186.33.99
```